# A problem occurred while processing the request (Jenkins) in Freestyle project

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment, cicd

I am trying to execute a CI/CD project. Everytime i am trying to create a job and trying to save my job it pops up an error. I have gone through a few issues available on the internet, but none of them have resolved the issue.
Can anybody help in this regard? Thanks

```
Tomcat 9 Server
Java 16.0.1
Jenkins 2.361.1
```

[image: After pressing "Apply" in freestyle project]
[image: After pressing "Save" in freestyle project]

Comment: Check your Tomcat logs to find the exact reason for the failure.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest do following:

1. Check the Jenkins logs on server and try to fix.
2. If don't work, try to restart your Jenkins.